# How can I tint an image using the ImageJ API

Tags: api, imagej

I am new to ImageJ and I am seeking to tint an image using the programmatic API of ImageJ.

- Is it possible? If so how?
- Where is the relevant documentation/Javadocs regarding image tinting with ImageJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image > Adjust > Color Balance…` is a good starting point; it's discussed in [`§28.2.3 Color Balance…`](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-28.html#toc-Subsection-28.2).